# precalculating node-set via copy-of and accessing ancestors (XSLT 1.0)

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to precalculate a subtree of nodes in an source XML, and the process them seperately (because I want the subset to be processed in different ways), and access some values from ancestors.

simple example

```
<numbers count="5">
  <number value="1"/>
  <number value="2"/>
  <number value="3"/>
  <number value="4"/>
  <number value="5"/>
</numbers>
```

and lets say I have an xslt (MSXML) to extract the even nodes somehow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <evens>
      <xsl:for-each select="numbers/number">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@value mod 2 = 0">
            <even>
              <xsl:attribute name="count">
                <xsl:value-of select="../@count"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="value">
                <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
            </even>
          </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </evens>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and we get..

```
<evens>
  <even count="5" value="2" />
  <even count="5" value="4" />
</evens>
```

nice...

but how can I seperate the filtering from the processing so something like...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template name="calculateNodes">
    <xsl:for-each select="numbers/number">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@value mod 2 = 0">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="nodes">
      <xsl:call-template name="calculateNodes"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <evens>
      <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($nodes)/number">
        <even>
          <xsl:attribute name="count">
            <xsl:value-of select="../@count"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </even>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </evens>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this gives.

```
<evens>
  <even count="" value="2" />
  <even count="" value="4" />
</evens>
```

so...the ancestors arent copied.

Is there an idiomatic way to get out of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A copied node exists on its own, outside of the original tree. In your example, the parent of `number` is the `$nodes` variable, which does not have any attributes.

Why don't you do simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/numbers">
    <xsl:variable name="nodes" select="number[@value mod 2 = 1]"/>
    <evens>
        <xsl:for-each select="$nodes">
            <even count="{../@count}" value="{@value}"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </evens>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This way you have a variable containing a *reference* to the original nodes, instead of a *copy*. Then you also have access to the original parent. And the content of the variable is a node-set; you don't need to convert it.

Comment: the example is deliberately simple, I want to calculate the set, but when processing them, access some attribute from the parent of the set.

Comment: Simple examples are best. In general, you have two options: (1) calculate the set within the `select` attribute of `xsl:variable` (as shown in my example); then your variable will contain a reference to the original nodes and their parent's values remain accessible. Or (2) populate your variable with **new** nodes and make sure they have all the values you will need later. Copying a node creates a new one. If you only copy the node and do not add the value from its parent, you won't be able to access it later (as you found out).

Comment: I like 2...very much...I've been trying to do it, but I can't get it to work

Comment: actually let me persevere, I can get something

Comment: I'll mark yours as the answer...because you basically did answer it...I just couldnt get it to work and was thinking it wouldnt.

Comment: I don't know what your real use case is, but in general you should always prefer (1) to (2). (2) is sometimes unavoidable, but never desirable.

Comment: its either do that, or recalculate the set multiple times in xslt...which of course is worse...I've got it to work...though with the real example, I'm struggling to match my "new" node....I think its been put in a namespace (I'm creating office xml)...I'm a bit of a xslt noob.

Comment: No. The set is calculated once, when the variable is created. At least that's how it should be with a well-designed XSLT processor.

Comment: I created my own namespace declaration and returned a new node in that namespace, that I could then match. By the way, why is this "undesirable", it seems quite a powerful paradigm, that would be quite common elsewhere (its a bit like a "query", with a seperate "from" and "map")

Comment: It is undesirable because of the extra processing required to create a new tree and populate it with new nodes, instead of just referencing existing nodes in the original tree. And also because in XSLT 1.0 the new tree is a result-tree-fragment and needs to be converted to a node-set if you want to process it further. So in the end it's more work for the programmer and for the computer. And I didn't even mention memory usage, which could be a factor when processing large documents.

Comment: ah ok, if I'm using it to create a node-set once and then just processing it in different ways, then....its less work for me? (I only write it once) its less work for the computer? (its in memory?) ....but it obviously takes some space?...the tree is immutable, so it wouldnt actually have to copy anything.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template name="calculateNodes">
    <xsl:for-each select="numbers/number">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@value mod 2 = 0">
          <numberWrapper>
            <xsl:attribute name="count">
              <xsl:value-of select="../@count"/>            
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          </numberWrapper>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="nodes">
      <xsl:call-template name="calculateNodes"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <evens>
      <xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($nodes)/numberWrapper">
        <even>
          <xsl:attribute name="count">
            <xsl:value-of select="@count"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="number/@value"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </even>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </evens>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```